# How to break a large CSV data file into individual data files?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file the first row of which contains the variables names and the rest of the rows contains the data. What's a good way to break it up into files each containing just one variable in Python? Is this solution going to be robust? E.g. what if the input file is 100G in size? I am trying to perform a divide conquer strategy but is new to Python. Thanks in advance for your help!

The input files looks like

```
var1,var2,var3
1,2,hello
2,5,yay
...
```

I want to create 3 (or however many variables) files var1.csv, var2.csv, var3.csv
so that files resemble
**File1**

```
var1
1
2
...
```

**File2**

```
var2
2
5
...
```

**File3**

```
var3
hello
yay
```

Comment: wanting to do that is likely to be much more of a problem than the implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lomg as the number of columns isn't absurdly huge (larger than the number of files you can have open at once on your platform), the number of rows, and thus the total size, are no big deal (as long of course as you have ample free space on disk;-) since you'll be processing just a column at a time -- I suggest the following code:

```
import csv

def splitit(inputfilename):
  with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as inf:
    inrd = csv.reader(inf)
    names = next(inrd)
    outfiles = [open(n+'.csv', 'wb') for n in names]
    ouwr = [csv.writer(w) for w in outfiles]
    for w, n in zip(ouwr, names):
      w.writerow([n])
    for row in inrd:
      for w, r in zip(ouwr, row):
        ouwr.writerow([r])
    for o in outfiles: o.close()
```

Comment: minor nitpicks: I suppose you meant w.writerow instead of ouwr.writerow -- w being the csvwriter instance in list: ouwr. Also, the nested loop "zip(ouwr, r)" should be "zip(ouwr, row)" and for o in outfile - should be for o in outfiles. 
Also, it works.

Comment: I had to play around with the code a little bit to get it working. Let me test it on a really large dataset, then I will give u the tick you deserve! Thanks

Comment: @bhangm, thanks for spotting the issues -- gonna edit to fix them, and, +1!-)

Answer (score 1):

Open n output files, one input file and read a line at a time. Chop the line up and write the n pieces to each file. You only ever store one line in memory each time, (and I presume the line is not 100GB?)

Answer (score 1):

if Python is not a must,

```
awk -F"," 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=$i}NR>1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i>a[i]".txt"}}' file
```

Comment: Would awk be faster than Python?

Comment: I am a complete noob. What's a good awk implementation on Windows?

Comment: go here : gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html. Look for gawk. There are other *nix tools as well, especially coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is 100GB, then disc IO will be your bottleneck. Consider using the [`gzip` module](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html) for both read (a precompressed file) and write to speed things up drastically.

Comment: Thanks for that. Useful! I am doing it to a SSD and it's still slow. Might give gzip a crack sometime

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/ruzne/querying-transforming-csv-using-sql.texy

```
crunch input.csv output.csv "SELECT AVG(duration) AS durAvg FROM (SELECT * FROM indata ORDER BY duration LIMIT 2 OFFSET 6)"
```

Answer (score 0):

use chunksize to get a chunk of data, then random write the chunk to different files.

```
df_reader = pd.read_csv("large_file.csv", chunksize=10)

mychunk=next(df_reader)

or

for chunk in pd.read_csv('large_file.csv', chunksize=10):

   #random choice a file to write to
```